# JAVA Date Conversion

Tags: java, datetime, date, date-conversion

How can I convert

```
Wed Apr 27 17:53:48 PKT 2011
```

to

```
Apr 27, 2011 5:53:48 PM.
```

Comment: You have the date object and you're asking how to output it differently , or you have the first String and you want to convert it to the 2nd one via Date?

Comment: I have a date object and I want to output it differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a.").format(yourDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SimpleDateFormat or JodaTime's parser.

However it might be simple enough to write your own String parser as you are just rearranging fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

String str = sdf.format(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a mix of JDK and [Joda time](http://joda.sourceforge.net/):

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class SO5804637 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat df = 
            new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        Date d = df.parse("Wed Apr 27 17:53:48 PKT 2011");
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = 
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(d);
        System.out.println(dt.toString(dtf));
    }

}
```

Note: I've included the `import` statements to make it clear what classes I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to convert a string to a date in a defined date presentation. An example of the SimpleDateFormat usage can be found at the following place: http://www.kodejava.org/examples/19.html

Answer (score 0):

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a").format(date);
```

I noticed your desired output had the hour of day not prefixed by 0 so the format string you need should have only a single 'h'. I'm guessing you want the day of the month to have a similar behavior so the pattern contains only a single 'd' too.